# UIPageControl: creating views in storyboards, add them as a child, change the label's text

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I've followed this tutorial: http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=168 for setting up the UIPageControl. Now as you can see in the tutorial, there are 3 views in the storyboard. And what I want to do is this:

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=f3cs2b&s=6

Because I need many views with the same layout (in the picture its just the background that is orange) I need to be able to reuse them and change the text on it, or create a button, etc.

I can add the views like this:

```
    UIViewController *aViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"];
    [self addChildViewController:aViewController];
```

But what if I wanted to change the text from the label that is on the view?

I was thinking about something like this:

```
    UIViewController *aViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"];
    // Change the text label thats on the viewcontroller, put an image on the UIImage thats on it, etc...
    [self addChildViewController:aViewController]; // After all that, add it as a child
    //Now I want the same layout template, so I choose the "View1" again
   UIViewController *aViewController2 = [self.storyboard                         instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"];
    // Again change the text label.
    [self addChildViewController:aViewController2]; // Add this new one too 
    // And so on
```

In my picture I copied the View 1, but I need to be able to do this is code, and not on the storyboard since I need more then 100 views.

Comment: As I suggested in your other question. Do a for - loop...

Comment: But how do I add content to the aViewController? Something like [aViewController setTextLabel:"text"]; isn't working

Comment: So if there is a label on the aViewController, how do I change it?

Comment: [aViewController.textLabel setText:@"Your text"]

Comment: and the ".textLabel", where do I get that from? I've put a label on the view in the storyboard...

Comment: Enough is enough. If you are having problem with this I suggest looking at some of the basic Objective-C tutorials available. Start with lecture 1-10 [here](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLA138EFCAFA592E7E). Stackoverflow do not exist so that other people can write your code for you. No hard feelings but please look at the tutorials.

Comment: I think I figured it out, for each view that got a different layout, I need to make a class and link this class with the view.